# Linking to SFML libraries without libsfml-dev

Tags: c++, linux, sfml

I currently have my Other Linker Options as:

[image: Other Linker Options]

Unfortunately, this means that I can only ever run the executable when `libsfml-dev` is installed, which is undesirable for game development. Whenever I even change the Other Linker Options or Search Directories>Linker will cause an error along the lines of:
`error while loading shared libraries: libsfml-graphics.so.2.2.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. I assume this error happens because the libraries are relative, so it is completely portable.

#### EDIT:

I am using Code::Blocks (as you can see from the image), and I would like to know how I can link to the libraries relatively. They link fine when it is run from Code::Blocks, but when I run the executable I get the above error. My current Code::Blocks options are:

Linker Options:

[image: Linker Options]

(Other linker options is empty)

Search Directories:

[image: Search Directories]

Comment: *this means that I can only ever run the executable when libsfml-dev is installed* -> that's called a dependency, nothing's wrong with that, especially on *nix system with their package manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first linker options would be the correct ones. 
The Library `libsfml-dev` is only required on the compile machine.

There must also be another package which actually supplies the .so files. That one will also be required on the machine running the executable unless you package those .so files with your executable. In that case you probably need a script that sets `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the local directory containing the packaged .so files and then executes your program.

Comment: How do I change the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: And also, I'd like to be able to move the folder the game is in, but your answer infers that I'd have an installation script which changes the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, unless I can run the script with C++, before I get a linker error (probably impossible)

Comment: You can set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with the `export` command from a shell script. You'd have to run your exe through this script. You can set the path to the directory the script/exe is in. The script can do this dynamically so you don't have to hardcode the path.

Comment: Ahh, I see, I've never made a shell script before, but I'll try that

Comment: I made the bash script, which took me way too long considering all it did was get the current directory and set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (*damn spaces in directories*) but it works perfectly!